# Add autoplay to ytplayer

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, autoplay, ytplayer

How do I add autoplay to the code below?

The HTML and JavaScript code below shows a simple example that inserts a YouTube player into the page element that has an id value of ytplayer. The onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() function specified here is called automatically when the IFrame Player API code has loaded. This code does not define any player parameters and also does not define other event handlers.

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
  height: '360',
  width: '640',
  videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `playerVars`, and add the `autoplay` property and set it to `1`

```
var  player = new YT.Player('youtube_videos_url', {
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 },
});
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: please take some time to explain how this solves the problem so that other with similar problem can know the issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `playVideo()` on `onPlayerReady` event.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Complete code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
        <div id="player"></div>

        <script>
         // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
         var tag = document.createElement('script');

         tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
         var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

         // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
         //    after the API code downloads.
         var player;
         function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
             player = new YT.Player('player', {
                 height: '390',
                 width: '640',
                 videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                 events: {
                     'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                     'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                 }
             });
         }

         // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
         function onPlayerReady(event) {
             event.target.playVideo();
         }

         // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
         //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
         //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
         var done = false;
         function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
             if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                 setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                 done = true;
             }
         }
         function stopVideo() {
             player.stopVideo();
         }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already done this before in my project so to do this please follow the steps

**step-1**

Add the iframe in which our youtube videos is load.Do like this

```
<iframe width="100%" height="378" id="youtube_url" allowfullscreen="1" class="vjs-default-skin" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rk6_hdRtJOE?wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&version=3&autoplay=0&controls=0&playerapiid=youtube_player&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0">
        </iframe>
```

**Step2**

And then add the YouTube iframe API

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

**Step-3**

Then use this code to create YouTube API object and use that to cotroller the video like auto play etc.

```
 var  player = new YT.Player('youtube_videos_url', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }

        });
function onPlayerReady(event) {
player.playVideo();
}
```

This code will run when our video loaded then `player.playVideo();` play you video automatically.

I thing it will help you.